# How to block my images from being displayed by other websites?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is anti-hotlinking done?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10838/how-is-anti-hotlinking-done)

I have a lot of images on my site and I don`t want to let other people to use my images on their sites. Is there any way to block the use of my images from other sites, maybe with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https?://www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https?://subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://google.com/thief.png [R,NC,L]
```

to allow people view images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https?://www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  !^https?://subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://google.com/thief.png [R,NC,L]
```

Comment: **Note**: if you want to enable users to view image by typing URL in address bar, remove Second line!

Comment: Only removing the second line wont allow people to view the image by typing the url directly into the address bar

Comment: @Tom you're right, I'll change the code